# Min and max values for KendoUI grid numeric textbox filter is not working

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have KendoUI grid in my application. There is one column that has "type:number", so in the grid filter menu a numeric text box is appearing. I want to set the min and max values for that numeric text box in filter menu. I tried to do this:

```
filterable: { 
    min:0,
    max:5,
    extra: false, 
    operators: { 
        number: {
            eq: "Is Equal To",
            neq: "Is Not Equal To"
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not working. Why? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid's `filterMenuInit` event to get a reference to the numeric textbox widget and set it's min & max values. Here's an example:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    // other config options omitted for brevity...
    filterable: { 
        extra: false, 
        operators: { 
            number: {
                eq: "Is Equal To",
                neq: "Is Not Equal To"
            }
        }
    },
    filterMenuInit: function(e) {
        var numeric;
        if (e.field === "my-field-name") {
            numeric = e.container
                .find("[data-role=numerictextbox]")
                .getKendoNumericTextBox();
            if (numeric) {
                numeric.min(0);
                numeric.max(5)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Check out the [KendoUI grid documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-filterMenuInit) for more details.